# C code to extract another file

Tags: c

I want to make a **C program** to extract another **binary file** to disk. The form of

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("libcurl.dll", "w");
fprintf(fp,"*OKJBJK09lkjhjG(**(G*I*()(KLJ(FG");
fprintf(fp,"fsd3r03rf-0)(-+_)H0F09E00FDS4asa");
......
```

Yes, the "w" mode and the ASCII text in the quotes make me a dumbo but please try to get the point.

```
char c[129];
fp1=fopen("source.dll", "r");
fp2=fopen("dest.c", "w");
while(!eof(fp1))
{
for(i=0;i<128;c[i]=fgetc(fp1));
fprintf(fp2,   "fprintf(fp,\"%s\");",   c);
}
```

This code is also crap...

I want to use it for extracting **DLLs and EXEs**, not text files. Question is, how do I generate the appropriate string from the data, and how to faithfully write them to disk?

I want to do it in C. So no automatic installers.

Comment: I think you should try to explain a bit clearer what it is you want to do. Do you want your program to open one file, and then write out each byte of that file into another file, essentially creating a copy? Or should the written version of each byte be in a different format (C source code)?

Comment: You need to use binary mode in the fopen 2nd argument: `fopen(..., "rb")` or `fopen(.., "wb")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to create a C file that you can compile to write binary data to a file when it is executed. Here is some code to do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp1=fopen("source.dll", "rb");
  FILE *fp2=fopen("dest.c", "w");

  if ((fp1 == NULL) || (fp2 == NULL))
  {
    printf("Unable to open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  fputs("#include <stdio.h>\n", fp2);
  fputs("int main(void)\n", fp2);
  fputs("{\n", fp2);
  fputs("  unsigned char file_data[] = {\n    ", fp2);

  while(!feof(fp1))
  {
    int len;
    int i;
    unsigned char buf[4096];
    len = fread(buf, 1, 4096, fp1);
    if (len <= 0)
    {
      break;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      fprintf(fp2,   "0x%02x, ", buf[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fp2, "\n    ");
  }
  fclose(fp1);
  fputs("  };\n", fp2);
  fputs("  FILE *fh = fopen(\"file.bin\", \"wb\");\n", fp2);
  fputs("  if (fh == NULL) { perror(\"fopen\"); return 1; }\n", fp2);
  fputs("  if (fwrite(file_data, 1, sizeof(file_data), fh) < 1)\n", fp2);
  fputs("    { perror(\"fwrite\"); return 1; }\n", fp2);
  fputs("  if (fclose(fh) != 0) { perror(\"fclose\"); return 1; }\n", fp2);
  fputs("  return 0;\n", fp2);
  fputs("}\n", fp2);
  fclose(fp2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm!! It's much better than what I had in my mind. I was busting my mind on lots of bin2c examples.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
FILE *fin=fopen("source.dll", "r");
FILE *fout=fopen("source_dll.h", "w");

int size=0;
fprintf(fout,"char *source_dll_bytes={");

while(!feof(fin))
  fprintf(fout, "%s%d", size++==0?"":",", fgetc(fin));

fprintf(fout, "};\nint source_dll_size=%d;", size);

fclose(fout);
fclose(fin);
```

Then you just `#include "source_dll.h"` and use `source_dll_bytes` and `source_dll_size` to print it out at runtime.

Edit: Just in case it wasn't clear, `fprintf` **will not work** to write binary data to a file on disk. Use `fwrite` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Binary files are stored in a specific *format*. Only the intended program that loads binary files knows the format and *interprets* the file content accordingly.

For example, suppose you want to write two integers in a binary file. Each integer will take 4 bytes, so the binary file will be of 8 bytes in size. Let's say, the numbers are 16 and 32 and also assume that everything is little endian.

The file content will look like as follows in hexadecimal:

```
1000000020000000
```

Now, how the file will look like if they are read in ASCII mode (like openning them in Notepad)? The data will look gibberish.

The intended program which is supposed to read the binary files knows that there are two integers there, each having 4 bytes long. So the program will read first 4 bytes from the file and interpret them as an integer. The program will do the same for next 4 bytes.

DLLs and EXEs are written in specific format as well and you need to know first what is the format. Then you can extract the data from them.

Comment: That specific format is Portable Executable 32 or 64 bit, possibly with .net extensions.